Extracting a number from Column in Excel -Python
Please advise on a question I have. I want to extract the year number from the column named "birth_date "( shown in attached screenshot). example: 1850-09-20. I want to extract "1850" number and put it in a new column. Can anyone please advise how to do it?

I started with below code but giving error (little newbie). Tried some help notes, but did not help: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html
import pandas as pd
df_data =pd.read_csv('nobel_prize_data.csv')
df_data['birth_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['birth_date'])



Try something like this to find which row is causing the problem

Please post pictures not as links but as embedded pictures. Also, don't post pictures of codes and error, just copy-paste it here and format it accordingly. Did you try two recommended solutions provided in the end of error picture you showed us?

The date format is a mix of formats, not just 'yyyy-mm-dd', but something like 12-5-1901.

You can extract details from column by splitting the string
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
  "Dates": ["1850-09-20", "1850-09-21", "1851-09-20"],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
pd.DataFrame(df1.Dates.str.split('-').tolist(),columns=["Year","Month","Day"])

Output :-

Or in Another way,
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
  "Dates": ["1850-09-20", "1850-09-21", "1851-09-20"],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1["Dates"]=pd.to_datetime(df1.Dates)
df1["Year"]=df1.Dates.dt.strftime('%Y')
df1["Month"]=df1.Dates.dt.strftime('%m')
df1["Day"]=df1.Dates.dt.strftime('%d')
df1

Output :-


Hi Atharv,  Thank you. The csv file has 2 different birth_dates format. 1850-09-20 and 6/17/1903 . The Error I see is : "ValueError: time data "12/5/1901" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d", at position 166. You might want to try:
- passing format if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing format='ISO8601' if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing format='mixed', and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use dayfirst alongside this.
